# Issue in Zend Translation

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-translate

There was issue with the msgid and msgstr in zend translation

define - en_US.PO

```
msgid "hello"

msgstr "hello world"
```

View/index.phtml

```
$this->translate("hello");
```

I would like to show "hello world" when I am trying to using msgid "hello" then it shows me "hello" instead of "hello world".

Please help me out what I have to do for that?

Comment: It appears like your translation-file isn't loaded. Check if the correct locale is set and if you set the correct default translation adapter. If no translation is found, the msgid is returned.

Comment: Can you show us what your module.config.php file looks like with your translation configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your module.config.php file

```
),
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```